# JavaScript Bit Manipulation to C++ Bit Manipulation

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

The following Pseudo and JavaScript code is a extract from the implementation of a algorithm , i want to convert it to C++ .

Pseudo Code :

```
for b from 0 to 2|R| do
for i from 0 to |R| do
if BIT-AT(b, i) = 1 then // b’s bit at index i
```

JavaScript Code :

```
for (var b = 0; b < Math.pow(2, orders[r].length); b++) // use b's bits for directions
   {
   for (var i = 0; i < orders[r].length; i++)
    {
    if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1) {  // is b's bit at index i on?
```

I don't understand what is happening in the last line of this code , What Should be the C++ code for the above given JavaScript code . So far what i have written is :

```
for (int b = 0; b < pow(2, orders.at(r).size()); b++) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < orders.at(r).size(); i++)
    {
     if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1)***//This line is not doing what it is supposed to do according to pseudo code***
```

The last line is giving me segmentation fault .

--
Edit:I apologize the problem was somewhere else , This code works fine .

Comment: As singer says, this code looks correct. If the C++ code isn't doing what it is supposed to do, what is it doing instead (and what is it supposed to be doing?). I would guess the problem is else where, possibly the difference between orders[r].length and orders.at(r).size.

Comment: It is giving me a segmentation fault . It  is supposed to be doing what is written in the pseudo code and what JavaScript code is doing .

Comment: @rajat, well if the problem is segfault, it would have been a good idea to say that in the question. Segfault cant be caused by bit operations here, it's probably either at `orders.at(r)`, or in the part of code that you have not posted. Debug it to see where it happens.

Comment: Everything else is fine , i output-ed the values of orders.at(r).size() and others . they are fine . Also i should mention that the error occurs in the starting , when b=0 and i=0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(((b >> i) & 1) == 1)
     |     |
     |     |
     |    bitwise AND between the result of the shift and number 1.
     |
    shift b by i bits to the right
```

After that the result is compared with the number 1.

So if, for example, `b` is 8, and `i` is 2, it will do the following:

1. shift 8 (which is `00001000`) by 2 bits to the right. The result will be `00000100`.
2. apply the bitwise AND: `00000100 BITWISE_AND 00000001`, the result will be `0`.
3. Compare it with 1. Since `0 =/= 1`, you will not enter that last `if`.

As for the logic behind this, the code `((b >> i) & 1) == 1)` returns `true` if the bit number `i` of the `b` variable is `1`, and `false` otherwise.

And I believe that c++ code will be the same, with the exception that we don't have `Math` class in c++, and you'll have to replace `var`s with the corresponding types.

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is the right shift operator, i.e. take the left operand and move its bit n positions to the right (defined by the right operand).

So essentially, `1 << 5` would move `1` to `100000`.

In your example `(b >> i) & 1 == 1` will check whether the i-th bit is set (1) due to the logical and (`&`).

As for your code, you can use it (almost) directly in C or C++. `Math.pow()` would become `pow()` inside `math.h`, but (in this case) you could simply use the left shift operator:

```
for (int b = 0; b < (1 << orders[r].length); ++b) // added the brackets to make it easier to read
    for (int i = 0; i < orders[r].length; ++i)
        if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1) {
            // ...
        }
```

`1 << orders[r].length` will essentially be the same as `pow(2, orders[r].length)`, but without any function call.

Comment: Why are doing ++b instead of ++b, what is the point of increasing the value before the function ?

Comment: I'm just used to doing it that way. Usually a pre-increment (++b) is always faster (not relying on the compiler to notice there wouldn't be any difference), as for pos-tincrement (b++) you'll have to keep a copy of the value. This is especially true for more complex data types (e.g. iterators), where using pre-increment is usually recommended. To emphasise this: The "keep a copy" mechanic isn't part of the compiler generated code if you're not using atomic stuff (like integers or pointers), so it might be impossible to just strip it away.